# How can I set up a Windows build in Xcode with Cocotron?

Tags: objective-c, windows, xcode, cocoa, cocotron

I have Cocotron set up, I have compiled the Foundation for Windows, and I have set up a project that uses that Foundation. I can't compile the project for Windows though, nor have I been able to find a guide to do so. Does anybody have any ideas to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a working Mac project. Duplicate the Mac target and change its name to Windows, and change the build settings as described here: http://www.cocotron.org/Tools/Build_Settings/?path=Tools/Build_Settings

It's actually shockingly easy. Note that if you use the script at `Cocotron/1.0/bin/retargetBundle`, you don't even need to figure out how to install the Foundation DLL.

Make sure you add Cocotron's Foundation.framework to your project: Cocoa.framework doesn't actually include Foundation and AppKit properly like it does on OS X.

Comment: I didnt see that, im new to this =D

Comment: Yes, but unless it's related to my specific answer you should post it as a separate question from this one.